# how to secure docker containers with iptables

Tags: ubuntu, docker, firewall, iptables, ufw

I'am trying protect containers from external IP access "0.0.0.0"

I would like to configure some containers to public access and others restrict to certains IPs.

```
sudo iptables -N DOCKER-USER
sudo iptables -I DOCKER-USER -j DROP

# where x.x.x.x is external IP allowed
sudo iptables -I DOCKER-USER -s x.x.x.x -j ACCEPT

# where yyyy is the external port that will be allow
sudo iptables -I DOCKER-USER -p tcp --dport yyyy -j ACCEPT

sudo iptables -I FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER-USER
```

It's working normally, but after a restart, this configuration is been reset and stop works.

I already try put this script at **/etc/rc.local** but it doesn't executed after restart.

My environment is:

```
Client:
 Version:      17.05.0-ce
 API version:  1.29
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   89658be
 Built:        Thu May  4 22:10:54 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.05.0-ce
 API version:  1.29 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   89658be
 Built:        Thu May  4 22:10:54 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false
```

Answer (score 1):

You can save your current iptables configuration and then load it when the server is started:

```
iptables-save | sudo tee /etc/iptables.conf
```

Copy the following into /etc/rc.local

```
# Load iptables rules from this file
iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.conf
```